# Способы защиты пароля в php-файле

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая осуществляет коннект к PostgreSQL:

```
function getdb() {
    $credentials = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=some_db user=random password=12345abcd";
    $db = pg_connect($credentials) or die('Connection failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    return $db;
}
```

Как мне кажется, хранить пароль вот так просто, в коде, в строковом представлении совсем небезопасно. Есть ли способ подключиться к базе данных напрямую не указывая пароль? И можно ли не хранить пароли в виде строки в исполняемых файлах PHP?

Comment: Хранит конфиденциальную информацию на компьютере доступном для посторонних людей (как по сети, так и физически) вообще не следует. А так, в вашем случае, все ОК, пока php работает.

Comment: Другого способа все равно нет. Что бы вы ни сделали с паролем он должен будет в скрипте расшифроватся или еще каким то хитрым способом получится, но в итоге он все равно окажется в какой нибудь переменной в открытом виде и его можно будет получить видя код. Даже если пароль не известен, если злоумышленник получил доступ к компу где лежит скрипт он может сделать все, что угодно и потеря пароля к БД не будет иметь никакого значения

Comment: храните файл с паролями в файле, к которому ограничьте доступ на сервере, права вроде 555 или тому подобное.